# Bronze badge count gets truncated on the badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, user-interface

It's a very minor formatting issue, but I might as well point it out.

When looking at the list of people who have earned particular badges, it seems the columns are a bit too narrow for users with high rep and large numbers of badges.  This results in the number of bronze badges earned for some users being truncated.

Screenshots from the [proofreader badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/proofreader) page below.

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Internet Explorer 8 (yeah, 8 doesn't really count):
[image: Internet Exploder 8]

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue.

Comment: I used to have this fun "achievement" of going over the decimal limit of scores available in some games (e.g. money in Final Fantasy 2 on SNES). Looks like achievement is unlocke on SFF.SE as well.

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/number-of-bronze-badges-partially-visible) and [here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/bronze-badge-number-not-visible-on-flagging-page).

Comment: Cut off in Opera too.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been fixed by the recent CSS update to the user flair box:

[image]

Chrome 47, Windows 8.1

Comment: Yarp, but now that they've made usernames overflow to new lines, and [SS's name looks chopped-off](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), ahhh, poor SO css team...