# Number of badges gets cut off

Tags: bug, badges

This is similar to [Bronze badge count gets truncated on the badge page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/bronze-badge-count-gets-truncated-on-the-badge-page), but it occurs in a different place (and may not have the same fix).

This happens in the user info for questions and answers.

Chrome 36, Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

Firefox 31, Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

Also happens in IE (though I don't have a screenshot).

---

(Good job Thaddeus ;)